# need help in joining 3 views

Tags: sql, join

I want to join 3 views in sql.
Here is my code :

```
select v1.grantee, v1.privilege, granted_role, v3.privilege, table_name 
from dba_sys_privs v1, dba_role_privs v2 , dba_tab_privs v3 
where v1.grantee=v2.grantee and v1.grantee=v3.grantee and v1.grantee='USER1';
```

My problem is when dba_tab_privs or dba_role_privs do not contain any row which the grantee is user1 the result will be 0 rows, so what i need is to show the result with empty space in granted_role and v3.privilege and table_name columns in that case.
I also tried this code :

```
select utilisateur, Sys_privs, Role, Obj_privs, table_name
from
(select grantee as utilisateur, privilege as Sys_privs from dba_sys_privs where grantee='USER1'),
(select granted_role as Role from dba_role_privs where grantee='USER1'),
(select privilege as Obj_privs, table_name from dba_tab_privs where grantee='USER1');
```

but unfortunately the result is zero rows too.

Comment: you have to do an outer join between tables if the value may not exist in one of the two tables being joined. you'd then have to do an `isnull` or `coalesce` function call to return an empty string instead of `NULL`, which is the default value when no information exists in an outer-joined table.

Comment: These look like Oracle System Catalog views. You don't really want to perform a JOIN between `DBA_SYS_PRIVS` and `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` on just the `grantee` column. (One of them returns "system" privileges, the other returns privileges on objects, that'd give a semi-cartesian join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using deprecated syntax for joining, update those, and use `LEFT JOIN` to not exclude records from your result set where they don't exist in all three tables:

```
SELECT v1.grantee, v1.privilege, granted_role, v3.privilege, table_name 
FROM dba_sys_privs v1
LEFT JOIN dba_role_privs v2 
  ON v1.grantee=v2.grantee
LEFT JOIN dba_tab_privs v3 
  ON v1.grantee=v3.grantee
WHERE v1.grantee='USER1';
```

Edit:  Per spencer7593's comment, your `JOIN` criteria may be incomplete/illogical if these are Oracle System Catalog views as he mentions.

Comment: If those are Oracle System Catalog views, it doesn't make sense to join `DBA_SYS_PRIVS` with `DBA_TAB_PRIVS`.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for that, I'm not terribly familiar with Oracle, but I noted your comment after seeing it under the question.  That sounds like a separate issue, using `LEFT JOIN` should get the OP results, whether those results are what they're really after or not... hard to say.